# How do I repeatedly expect a sequence of calls?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I'm writing a test to verify the sequence of calls on an image processing thread.  The relevant piece of test code looks like this:

```
Sequence s1, s2;
...
EXPECT_CALL(*mMockVideoSource, getFrame()).InSequence(s2).WillRepeatedly(Return(mFakeBuffer));
EXPECT_CALL(*mMockProcessor, processFrame(_,_)).InSequence(s2).WillRepeatedly(Return(0));
EXPECT_CALL(*mMockVideoSource, releaseFrame(_)).Times(AnyNumber()).InSequence(s2);
...
```

In this case, the sequence of calls is extremely important.  `getFrame()`, `processFrame()` and `releaseFrame()` must be called in this order.  Unfortunately, the above code isn't really accomplishing what I want.  The above code will allow `getFrame()` to be called repeatedly before the call to `processFrame()`, and a call to `getFrame()` after `releaseFrame()` is considered an error since it breaks the sequence.

Is there a way to expect a specific sequence of calls to be made repeatedly?  I don't care how many times the sequence is executed, so long as the functions are called in order: get, process, release, get, process, release...

Comment: Why are you using `WillRepeatedly` then instead of e.g. `WillOnce`?

Comment: My goal is to allow the expectations to hold repeatedly.  If I use WillOnce, each call will only be allowed to be called one time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create side action on calling your mock (https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Combining_Actions) and some global state like "lastAction".

Side action will look like:

```
void checkSequenceCorrectness(ActionType currAction)
{
    if (currAction == PROCESS_FRAME) EXPECT_EQ(GET_FRAME, lastAction);
    (more ifs)
    ...

    lastAction = currAction;
}
```

You can bind it to mock by:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*mMockProcessor, processFrame(_,_))
    .WillRepeatedly(DoAll
        Return(0), 
        Invoke(checkSequenceCorrectness(PROCESS_FRAME)));
```

Comment: Oh, nice!  I'll give this a try tomorrow.  It certainly looks promising.